# How to validate jira whether all the datas migrated correctly after migrating the datas from jira 5 to jira 6

Tags: jira

I have finished the migration from jira 5 to jira 6. Now i want to check whether all the datas, attachments, issue types, workflow, screens etc is migrated correctly. Please provide me possible validation i can use to check my migration happened correctly.

Comment: Is there anything in the log files that makes you think it was not successful ?

Comment: no... but we need to check all the workflows, issue types, attachments of different project . It is client requirement. i want to know is der any script available to check all the things.

Comment: I'm not aware of any pre-done script.  Personally I would use sql to compare the databases directly: [Example jira SQL queries](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA041/Example+SQL+queries+for+JIRA)

Comment: Thank you very much. This will help me.